# Extract text from japanese .pdf file

Tags: php, pdf, yii, character-encoding

I'm working on an [PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/erj2x8c3ylfbf1b/10032016DKC_kensaku_a_0217.pdf?dl=0). I need to extract Japanese text only from a PDF file. And then **save it** into my database in type of string.

I've searched on Stack Overflow and page 4 of Google but cannot find a solution.

I'm trying on `pdfparser` of SMALOT at `github.com/smalot/pdfparser` but it just shows [unreadable characters (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CnW9.png)

Eg:

> \w ���w ��� � /�����yyy/� �Fq�J�yyy/�S�M��dyyy/�q�    �Cyyy/�>;   �Cyyy/��������yyy/�]b;tKh�yyy/��� ����y /����yyyy/� ��  �Cyyyyy/�   � a ���yyyy/���� wyyy/� a �Ugyyy/����� e{yyyy/�2�" Copyright(c)2014 Daiichikizai.,Co.,Ltd All rights reserved.

I'm using `Yii framework`, `PHP 5.5`

I tried `utf-encode()`, `utf-decode()`, `mb_convert_encoding()`, but nothing works.

**UPDATE:** I tried `mb_detect_encoding()` and it return `UTF-8`. So maybe not a encoding problem here.

Any suggestions would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: What kind of pdfviewer do you have? And Do you have the Eastern language support installed for your PDF viewer?

Comment: I'm using windows default PDF viewer. I'm sorry but what I need is extract text data from the PDF file so I can save on my database in type of string, not just viewing it.

Comment: Ok try to make your question even more accurate then. Add that comment information inside your question.

Comment: Can you provide the PDF in question?

Comment: @Setasign I updated the sample pdf file. Thank you.

Comment: The encoding is reported as Identity-H. That means the character indexes (`3e9`, `2FA3`, and so on) are not given in terms of Unicode, but as *specific character indexes* in the original font file. In the file, I cannot find a table to convert from these indexes to Unicode or any other regular encoding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read Japanese characters in a PDF file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431215/read-japanese-characters-in-a-pdf-file)

Comment: @RadLexus is correct. The mentioned script simply doesn't support predefined CMaps.

Comment: @Setasign & RadLexus thank you guys, can you tell me what can I do to retrieve those text please? I'm noob

Comment: I'm not aware of a GPL compatible solution in PHP, sorry.